# Android SDK Directory Destination

Tags: android, sdk, directory

I want to know if it's okay to drag the Android SDK folder, into the program files folder. Instead of having it in the user directory? Is it safe/recommended?

Comment: As long as you change all the references to it, it should be okay

Comment: I'm sorry but what are the references?

Comment: Keep in mind that program files folder requires admin access in most setups, so when you want to update the SDK you'll need to be in admin mode. For this reason I recommend not moving it there.

Comment: I see the point! Thanks! I will just move it to the user directory (:

Comment: Is this the user directory? C:\Users\Sebastian